# How does a wizard Halfling (Mark of Healing) learn the healing spells

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, healing, halfling

The race/species of Halfling (Mark of Healing) (ERLW, page 43) states

**Spells of the Mark.** If you have the Spellcasting or the Pact Magic class feature, the spells on the Mark of Healing Spells table *are added to the spell list of your spellcasting class.*

As a wizard, adding a spell to *your spellcasting class*, this would indicate that the spells are now wizard spells and can be added to your spellbook.

But, outside of the 2 spells per level, how can a wizard learn these spells? They just know them? From a cleric directly?  From a cleric written scroll?

Research shows somewhat conflicting answers about multiclass options and impact, but none reference a wizard who gains the spells from the dragon mark.

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Feel free to check our [tour], it explains how things work around here. We also have the [help] for more questions, but also feel free to simply ask them in comments or in a chat room. To answer your question, we need to know what game/system you're playing. Adding the relevant tag will solve that issue. (this looks like DnD 5e at first glance, but I could be wrong)

Answer (score 20):

### Via scroll-scribing as per the normal rules

While 5e does discriminate between, for example, cleric spell list, wizard spell list, sorcerer spell list, etc, what it does not discriminate with is 'scroll types'.

A shield scroll isn't marked as having been scribed by a wizard, sorcerer, battlesmith, or a hexblade, and any of the four can cast the spell from it, as long as the spell is on their personal class spell list and they meet the other casting requirements. The wizard can scribe this shield scroll into his book no matter who made it.

The same is true for scrolls of spells from the Mark of Healing, which are now part of your Wizard Spell List; they might be a little harder to find, depending on what your options for gathering such things are in the game, but if you can find, for example, a scroll of prayer of healing, you can scribe it into your wizard spellbook as a mark of healing character.

Answer (score 16):

### From another dragonmarked wizard

As [TheFallenOne's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/204819/28402) points out, a wizard can copy wizard spells from a spell scroll, those spells are now wizard spells for that character, and there's no reason that scrolls of those spells cannot exist.

However, there is another way that wizards can learn spells, and that's to copy them from another wizard's spellbook. As you've noted yourself, the independent spell research that you get to do as part of levelling up would allow your wizard to figure out these spells without needing to learn them from an external source. But once one wizard *has* done that, the spells now exist in a scribed format - all that is required for the next wizard to learn them is to be allowed to copy them from the first wizard's book.

Given the entanglement between dragonmarks and the Houses, a plausible option is that a dragonmarked wizard who is in good standing with their House could have access to that magical knowledge, provided by more accomplished wizards from the same House or at least the heirloom spellbooks of wizards from generations past.

Comment: Nice finish there in terms of using the setting as a way to look at this. 